# How to pass in dbConext to a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

In my `Seed()` method I have the following code that creates an initial user for my AspNetUsers table.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

    // Create the new user
    var user = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = "DefaultAdmin",
        Email = "default-admin@mydomain.com",
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        FirstName = "Default",
        LastName = "Admin",
        JoinDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
    };

    manager.Create(user, "DefaultAdmin");

    //Create the roles if they do not already exist
    if (roleManager.Roles.Count() == 0)
    {
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Administrator" });
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Employee" });
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Customer" });
    }

    // Find the newly created user asn assign to the Administrator role
    var adminUser = manager.FindByName("DefaultAdmin");
    manager.AddToRoles(adminUser.Id, new string[] { "Administrator" });
}
```

This `Seed()` method works just fine and creates the single user 'DefaultAdmin` in my AspNetUsers table and assigns it to the Administrator role.

I would like to use this same logic to import some existing users from a different database. However, I find when I am using this in the import method the user never actually gets saved to the table. I think it is because the `Seed()` method has access to the `dbContext` as it is passed into the `Seed()` method. My question is how do I pass in the `dbContext` to my `Import()` method?

My `Import()` method is called from an API endpoint and I can't figure out how to get the dbContext into the `Import()` method.

```
public static string ImportCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        var customerList = GetAllCustomers();

        foreach (var customerFromDb in customerList)
        {
            var manager = new customerManager<Applicationcustomer>(new Customerstore<Applicationcustomer>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            var customer = new ApplicationCustomer()
            {
                customerName = customerFromDb.customerName,
                customerId = customerFromDb.customerId,
                Email = customerFromDb.Email,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                FirstName = customerFromDb.FirstName,
                LastName = customerFromDb.LastName,
                JoinDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
            };

            // Assign the password
            manager.Create(customer, customerFromDb.Password);

            var newcustomer = manager.FindByName(customerFromDb.Email);
            manager.AddToRoles(newcustomer.Id, new string[] { "Customer" });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In this case the `newcustomer` is `null`

Comment: Do I misunderstand, or did you include the code for a method that works but omit the code for the one that has the problem?

Comment: Why not create a new DbContext in your Import method?

Comment: The `Import()` method is pretty much the same thing as the `Seed()` method but I don't have the dbContext.

Comment: I guess that is the issue for me. The `Seed()` method is passed the `dbContext` but I am unsure how to create the `dbContext` for the `Import()` method

Comment: new ApplicationDbContext();

Comment: But when I create the `manager` variable I am creating an instance of `ApplicationDbContext()`. Just like the Seed method does. But yet it is not working in the `ImportCustomers()` method

Comment: Did you call SaveChanges() for your context? Inside Seed() method it's not needed but every where else you must call SaveChanges() in order to persist the changes to the db.

Comment: No I didn't because of just the reason you mentioned. I figured since the `Seed()` method did not require it was being taken care of "behind the scenes". Why is it not needed in `Seed()`? Doesn't the UserManager handle the SaveChanges()?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I change the code so that I could get a result back from `manager.Create()`. As such `IdentityResult result = manager.Create(customer, customerFromDb.Password);`. Looking at the `IdentityResult` I could see the HasErrors property was not empty and had an error saying "Passwords must be at least 6 characters'. This did not happen in the `Seed()` method because the password requirements were met. Not the case in the import.